# Error: Unbound variable: *AJAX-PROCESSOR* using HT-SIMPLE-AJAX

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I'm using HT-SIMPLE-AJAX to provide a simple JSON structure over AJAX. It works beautifully if the function defined by `defun-ajax`is compiled **after** the lisp image and the server is started.

If I load the lisp program (with `ccl --load`) with the function defined, I get this error:

> Error: Unbound variable: *AJAX-PROCESSOR*
>   While executing: #, in process listener(1).
>
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
>   If continued: Skip loading "/home/hunchentoot/quicklisp/local-projects/gac-man/run.lisp"
>   Type :? for other options.

The function is as follows:

```
(defun-ajax machine-info (serial) (*ajax-processor*)
  (let* ((serialn (remove #\" serial)))
    (concatenate 'string
     "Lots of boring stuff" "here")))
```

The ajax processor is created in another function, called at the start of the program:

```
(defun start ()
  (setup)
  (connect-to-database)
  (defvar *web-server* (start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8080
                     :document-root #p"~/www/")))
  (defvar *ajax-processor* 
  (make-instance 'ajax-processor :server-uri "/ajax"))
  (print "Starting web server...")
  (setf *show-lisp-errors-p* t
    *show-lisp-backtraces-p* t)
  (define-easy-handler (docroot :uri "/") () (docroot)
  ....
  ....
   (setq *dispatch-table* (list 'dispatch-easy-handlers 
               (create-ajax-dispatcher *ajax-processor*)))))
```

And yet if I start everything and then compile in the function through slime later, it works just fine. Why is this error occurring?

I'm using Clozure Common Lisp on 64-bit Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your `defun-ajax` form is *loaded* before the `start` function has *run*.  That is not surprising.  Usually, all code is loaded, and only then the entry point is called.

You should always be very suspicious of `defvar`, `defun`, `defparameter` etc. forms appearing in a function body.  They don't belong there.  Put them as toplevel forms, so they are loaded as part of the program.  Most of the things defined during the run of the `start` function shown should really be toplevel forms.

Comment: Hi Svante, Thanks for the advice.I tried putting all of my parameters in toplevel forms and I still get the error. What I've done is created a lisp file with all of the defparameters/defvars etc which then calls the start function.

Comment: I pulled everything that wasn't in a clearly defined function into the top level and it worked! Thank you for your help.